# Cmake does not build static library on Windows

Tags: cmake

I have an odd problem where CMake on Windows run without trouble but then the compiler does not actually create the library

```
project(core)

find_package(spdlog REQUIRED)

set(core_gen_hdr "include/chrono.h" "include/monitoring.h" "${SPDLOG_HEADER_FILES}")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC "${core_gen_hdr}")

target_include_directories (${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "include/" "${SPDLOG_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

source_group("Header Files" FILES "${core_gen_hdr}")

set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY FOLDER ${MODULE_NAME})
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

I wonder if this is because the only source files are header files? When compiling, no library gets created, which creates problem with dependent libraries that want to link against the non-existing file.

CMake version is 3.5.0 and I build with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=cmake+header+only+library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an [`interface library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#interface-libraries)

In fact, `spdlog` is also header-only, and does just this (see [here](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L25))

For your project, you just need to add your project's include directories, and then link to `spdlog` and cmake will sort out the transitive dependencies

```
# create your library, specifying it is an interface-library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE)

# add your project's directories
target_include_directories(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    INTERFACE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

# link against spdlog, which is also just an interface-library
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} spdlog)
```